# Error Unable to instantiate service com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException- in Proguard Enabled release

Tags: android, firebase

I am getting below mentioned error,

I **cleaned** the project, also **Invalidate and restart** done. but still same problem.

Proguard is enabled.-android studio:3.3.1

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService" on path: DexPathList

Comment: share your proguard configuration file

Comment: Did you add the library in your build.gradle dependencies?

Comment: -keep class com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider only thing i kept related Firebase in Proguard

Answer (score 1):

Simple add `-keep class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService` in your ProGuard configuration file.